# There is no output in the following LaTeX code

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{Theorem}{Abstract}[abstract]
\newtheorem{deftn}{Defination}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
%\begin{document}
\title{article on Ramanujan}
\author{Hirak Jyoti Das \thanks {This author thanks CSIR for providing fellowship.\\ email: dashirakjyoti592@gmail.com}\\
 Department of Mathematical Sciences, Tezpur University, Assam.}\\
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
In this article we will briefly discuss about the life of great mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan. During his short lifetime, Ramanujan independently compiled nearly $3900$ results. Most of his claims have now been proven correct. He stated results that were both original and highly unconventional, such as Ramanujan prime and the Ramanujan theta function and these have inspired a vast amount of further research.Without any formal training in pure mathematics, he made extraordinary contributions to the mathematical analysis, number theory, infinite series etc. Living in India with no access to the larger mathematical community, Ramanujan developed his own mathematical research in isolation.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I remove the ``\\`` before `\date`, it works (it should produce output regardless, but the ``\\`` there causes an error).

Comment: ok..thanks a lot

Comment: would you please give your modified code?

Comment: Just remove the two backslashes  after “Assam”.

Answer (score 3):

If I run your document I get an error about the `\\` before `\date`:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.19 \date
        {\today}
?
```

With older releases, `\\` could not appear (unprotected) inside `\thanks` (thanks to campa for spotting this).  Prepending `\protect` to `\\` fixes that as well:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{Theorem}{Abstract}[abstract]
\newtheorem{deftn}{Defination}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
%\begin{document}
\title{article on Ramanujan}
\author{Hirak Jyoti Das \thanks {This author thanks CSIR for providing fellowship.\protect\\ email: dashirakjyoti592@gmail.com}\\
 Department of Mathematical Sciences, Tezpur University, Assam.} % \\ <-- removed
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
In this article we will briefly discuss about the life of great mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan. During his short lifetime, Ramanujan independently compiled nearly $3900$ results. Most of his claims have now been proven correct. He stated results that were both original and highly unconventional, such as Ramanujan prime and the Ramanujan theta function and these have inspired a vast amount of further research.Without any formal training in pure mathematics, he made extraordinary contributions to the mathematical analysis, number theory, infinite series etc. Living in India with no access to the larger mathematical community, Ramanujan developed his own mathematical research in isolation.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok. But still I am getting an error message at \begin{abstract} line.

Comment: @user255434 I can't possibly guess what error you are getting.  The document as I posted works (tested on TeX Live 2021, but probably in earlier versions too), so please show exactly what document you are compiling, and what the error is

Comment: @user255434 I can compile with an current MiKTeX without error the corrected code. Please show the error you get **in your question**. Copy it from the log file and paste it into your question ...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I *do* get an error from the ``\\`` in the argument of `\thanks`. Had to `\protect` it to make it work. (TL2017).

Comment: it can not be copied here

Comment: still the error message is coming

Comment: @campa AH, yes!  ``\\`` was recently made `\protected`, so it's reasonable it breaks with older releases.  Wanna post an answer with that, or should I edit mine?

Comment: Go on, it was just a guess.

Comment: @user255434 See the edit.  campa guessed (spot-on) the issue

Comment: Now it is just perfect. Very nice. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

May be try this one:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.0cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]
%\newtheorem{Theorem}{Abstract}[abstract]
\newtheorem{deftn}{Defination}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
%\begin{document}
\title{article on Ramanujan}
\author{Hirak Jyoti Das \thanks {This author thanks CSIR for providing fellowship. email: dashirakjyoti592@gmail.com}
 Department of Mathematical Sciences, Tezpur University, Assam.}
\date{\today}
\title{title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
    In this article we will briefly discuss about the life of great mathematician Srinivasa Ramanujan. During his short lifetime, Ramanujan independently compiled nearly $3900$ results. Most of his claims have now been proven correct. He stated results that were both original and highly unconventional, such as Ramanujan prime and the Ramanujan theta function and these have inspired a vast amount of further research.Without any formal training in pure mathematics, he made extraordinary contributions to the mathematical analysis, number theory, infinite series etc. Living in India with no access to the larger mathematical community, Ramanujan developed his own mathematical research in isolation.
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```